# Proof that there is no continuous 1-1 map from the unit circle in $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S^1=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$. I'm trying to prove that there is no 1-1 continuous mapping between $S^1$ and the real line. The map is not necessarily onto.

Proof so far:
Suppose such a function $f$ existed. Since $S^1$ is compact and $f$ is continuous and 1-1, $f$ inverse exists and is also continuous. Hence the range of $f$ is closed.

Not sure where to proceed next.

Comment: The inverse of a continuous bijection is not necessarily continuous. For example, the map $g: [0, 2\pi) \to S^1$ given by $g(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$ is a continuous bijection, but $[0, 2\pi)$ isn't compact, so $g^{-1}$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Removing an arbitrary point from $S^1$ leaves it connected. The image of $S^1$ under $f$ is a non-degenerate interval. Would removing an arbitrary point from it leave it connected?

Comment: David, ah, good point.

Comment: @DanielHast, the inverse of a continuous bijection with compact domain is continuous.

Comment: @IanKotliar: Ah, I didn't notice you were using compactness there. (Though what you said in your comment isn't quite correct as stated — we also need the assumption that the codomain is Hausdorff. For some counterexamples when this assumption is dropped, consider any continuous bijection from a discrete finite space to a non-discrete finite space.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks David! Your proof makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f:S^1\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous map. Write $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$, then $g$ is also continuous. As
$$g(-x) = f(-x) - f(-(-x)) = f(-x) - f(x) = -(f(x) - f(-x)) = -g(x), $$
$g$ is an odd function. If $g(x)=0$, then $f(x)=f(-x)$. If not, then $g(x)>0$ and $g(-x)<0$ or $g(x)<0$ and $g(-x)>0$. In either case, as $S^1$ is a connected subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, by the intermediate value theorem there exists $c$ between $x$ and $-x$ such that $g(c)=0$. Thus $f(c)-f(-c)=0$, so that $f(c)=f(-c)$. It follows that $f$ cannot be one-to-one.

Comment: Although the argument seems right, I don't think I understand it. As it is, it looks like the same argument could be applied for a $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function, but that can't be true.
Why this proof would fail for a $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function?

Comment: It wouldn't "fail," it would just imply that the function is constant.

Comment: what does exactly 'between $x$ and $-x$' mean?

Comment: @RIYASUDHEENT.K For example $-(1,0) = (-1,0)$.

Comment: 'Between' means what?

Answer (score 3):

let f: $S^1 $ $\rightarrow$ R is a 1-1 continuous map. Observe that Img(f) is a compact and connected subset of R (i.e a compact interval [a,b] for some real numbers a and b)and f is a bijective continuous map from $S^1$ to Img(f)...there is a theorem in point set topology that if F: X $\rightarrow$ Y is a continuous bijection map where X is compact and Y is hausdorff then F is a homeomorphism...
but you can prove that $S^1$ is not homeomorphic with Img(f).
(one way to show this you can compare there fundamental groups otherwise just take a point out from img(f) correspondingly take out of the inverse image of the same point then you can get one side a connected set on the other hand a disconnected set but restriction map is still a homeomorphism so either both should be connected or disconnected. That will give you an contradiction)

Comment: It's a brilliant approach