# No continuous injective map $f: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

A friend asked me if there could be a continuous injective map

$$f: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}.$$

My intuition tells me no. Endow $\mathbb{S}^1$ with a topology $\mathscr{T}$ and fix a pole $x \in \mathbb{S}^1$, consider $f(x)$ and take $B_\epsilon (f(x))$. Since $f$ is continuous,  $f^{-1}(B_\epsilon (f(x)))$ is open so take $N(x) \in \mathcal{N}(x)$ so that $N(x) \subset f^{-1}(B_\epsilon (f(x)))$.

Now I don't know enough topology to formalize my intuition. Namely, if $x_1$ is close on one "side" of $x$ and $x_2$ is close on the other side, then $f(x_1)$ is at most $\epsilon$ away from $f(x)$ and likewise with $f(x_2)$. So, either $f$ is constant or $f(x_2)$ approaches $f(x)$ as $x_2 \to x$, so that clearly there must be a point that is not injective.

So, how do I express this formally as a topological proof?

Comment: You take the standard topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$. You probably know that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is compact then. So every continuous $f\colon \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ attains ...

Comment: @AnthonyPeter with a different topology, the two spaces mihght even be homeomorphic. If we speak of $\mathbb S^ 1$ we better *always* mean the standard topology.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is compact, and there is an injective continuous map from that to $\mathbb{R}$. We need some further property of $\mathbb{S}^1$ beyond compactness.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is this property? Again, intuitively, it has something to do with the fact that I stated in my question.

Comment: Informally, that $\mathbb{S}^1$ has no endpoints.

Comment: @DanielFischer Formally?

Comment: $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a one-dimensional topological manifold; every point of $\mathbb{S}^1$ has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How now, do we put this all together. That is, the notion of $f$ attaining its extrema, and this homeomorphic property with $(-1,1)$?

Comment: Other questions about the impossibility of a continuous injection from a circle to a line: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1206394, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/728415, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1092148

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a continuous bijection from a compact set to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. If such a map $f$ exists, then $S^1$ is homeomorphic to its image, which is compact and connected in $\mathbb{R}^1$. But then this image is a bounded closed interval, whose boundary is nonempty while the boundary of $S^1$ is empty, a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

A hint:

No fiddling around with $\epsilon$'s here! You want to establish a certain global fact; therefore you have to bring in appropriate global tools, like the MVT, the fact that $S^1$ is compact, etc.

Full solution, pedestrian way:

Since $S^1$ is compact the function $f$ assumes a minimum $a$ at a point $z_a\in S^1$ and a maximum $b>a$ at a point $z_b\in S^1$. These two points split $S^1$ into two arcs $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$. On each of the two arcs the function $f$ has to assume the value $m:={a+b\over2}$ somewhere, which contradicts injectivity.

Comment: Are you specifically saying to apply the MVT in this case? I don't see how to do this outside of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

We show that there's a pair of antipodal points $p$ and $-p$ such that $f(p)=f(-p)$.  Suppose that such a pair doesn't exist.  Define $g(p):=f(p)-f(-p)$.  Then $g$ has no zeroes and is continuous. Since $g(-p)=-g(p)$ we conclude that $g$ takes positive and negative values, but $S^1$ is connected.